# LINQpad thread behaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, linqpad

I was just starting out on LinqPad and trying some thread snippets in it and I was bewildered as to why my code is not doing as predicted to do.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread
(delegate()
    {
        for (int cycles = 0; cycles < 1000; cycles++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
);
t1.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Soham");
```

Why is this only printing `Soham`. The code block inside the thread is not at all executing. I'm not able to understand why because the syntax compiles fine and as far as I I know about c# this should compile fine and run in VS2010 and execute both outputs, even though the order of which cannot be determined. What am I doing or thinking wrong here. I may need some useful tutorials and suggestions to get used to LinqPad.

Comment: Yes: this behavior is not intuitive. The good news is that is has changed in recent betas (linqpad.net/beta.aspx). Other threads now continue in LINQPad after the main thread has finished.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari Thanks joe. Excellent tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a `t1.Join()` after the `Console.WriteLine("Soham")` :-) The LINQPad probably sees the main thread terminating and kills everything. With the `t1.Join();` the main thread will wait for the other thread to finish.

Ah... and just tested it :-)

I'll add that you can write in less characters:

```
new Thread(() => 
{
```

Comment: Was just trying out some samples from Joseph Albahari's - [Threading  in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). Anyway thanks. On a sidenote, if you check out his first example, does calling the `Join` make the behavior of the `CLR` any different.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta It all depends on the order of scheduling and on how much time it takes from the main thread to finish. If the main thread takes at least some tens of a millisecond to finish there is a good chance the secondary thread can run. You can try it by adding a `Thread.Sleep(x)` at the end of the main thread (no `t1.Join` necessary) and changing the value. I would even move the `Thread.Sleep(500)` AFTER the `Console.WriteLine()` in the secondary thread.